# React Semantic UI Popup was hidden while "mouse click inside but release outside" of Popup block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

React Semantic UI Popup was hidden while "mouse click inside but release outside" of the Popup block.

I am creating a login popup component in React by using React Semantic UI Popup. I am using "Events triggering the popup on click". When I was trying to copy the content in the Popup block, the popup was closed when my mouse released outside of the popup box.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Message, Popup, Icon, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';

// code inside of render return function
<Popup trigger={<Button icon>LOGIN</Button>}
       on='click'
       className='login-popup'
>
       <div className='popup-main'>
              <Message attached='bottom'>
                        Log In
              </Message>
              <LoginForm
                  {...this.props}
              />
        </div>

        <Message attached='bottom'>
              Don't have account? Signup instead.
        </Message>
</Popup>
```

I would like to keep the Popup open unless the user clicks the mouse outside of the Popup. If the user clicked the mouse inside of the Popup Box, the Popup should not be closed even the mouse released outside of it.

Comment: interesting find :D. I think this is an issue of the library itself. I tried on their demo and they have same problem. It seems that they are listening on mouse up to release the popup

Comment: @ducmai I'm not sure if they designed their library like this. So, I didn't add this as an issue on their Github. Maybe I should do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flowing** or **pinned** attribute of the Popup.

```
<Popup
    trigger={<Button icon>LOGIN</Button>}
    on='click'
    className='login-popup'
    flowing
    >
       <div className='popup-main'>
          <Message attached='bottom'>Log In</Message>
          <LoginForm {...this.props}/>
       </div>

       <Message attached='bottom'>
           Don't have account? Signup instead.
       </Message>
</Popup>
```